# Access VBA - Adding up Min:Sec field to total seconds

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a duration field in my database table, that has a duration in this format "00:00" minutes and seconds respectively. The field is a short text.

I need to tally up these durations in a report, into a sum of seconds. I tried doing a sum of the field as is, but it didn't return the right value.

I'm at a loss - I don't know how to go about doing this in Access. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "HrSec" to match your field's name:

`Sum(Left([HrSec],InStr(1,[HrSec],":")-1)*60+Right([HrSec],2))`

If all entries in your column are formatted 00:00 and not 0:00, then you can use the following which is slightly simplier:

`Sum(Left([HrSec],2)*60+Right([HrSec],2))`